# System init file

Tags: linux, quota, sles

I need to enable quota's in my linux system. As mentioned in  [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Quota-3.html) article which suggests to run quotaon command in sysinit file.

I am using Suse Linux Enterprise Edition. Where can I find this file. I have checked /etc/rc.d directory. But it does not have rc.sysinit file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2003-08-09 is a little bit old and Linux systems have changed since then.

You should consult the SLES administration manuals which you can find under http://www.novell.com/documentation/sles10/#administration

I wouldn't also be surprised if there was an appropriate YaST module for quota configuration.

Comment: The relevant documentation is found here: http://www.novell.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_deployment/?page=/documentation/sles11/book_sle_deployment/data/sec_y2_userman_adv.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm a redhat guy, so I am not an expert on suse, but based on the one suse host I have access to the suse equivalent to `rc.sysinit` is `/etc/init.d/boot`

`rc.sysinit` (on redhat systems) is the script that init calls to kick off the startup process.

Basically you need to check you `/etc/inittab` for lines that contain `sysinit`, `boot` or `bootwait` and it will be the script specified in one of those lines.

On the suse system I have access to the relevant line in `/etc/inittab` looks like this:

```
# First script to be executed, if not booting in emergency (-b) mode
si::bootwait:/etc/init.d/boot
```

See `man inittab` for more details.